# Delete a prime number in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, primes, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}*head=NULL;

int length(struct node *p)
{
    int len;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        len++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return len;
}

void display(struct node *p)
{
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Linked List: ");
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", p->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}

void insert(struct node *p, int index, int x)
{
    struct node *t;
    if(index == 0)
    {
        t = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = x;
        t->next = head;
        t->prev = NULL;
        if(head != NULL)
        {
            head->prev = t;
        }
        head = t;
    }
    else
    {
        t = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = x;

        for(int i=0; i<index-1; i++)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        t->prev = p;
        t->next = p->next;
        if(p->next != NULL)
        {
            p->next->prev = t;
        }
        p->next = t;
    }
}

int checkprime(int n)
{
    int prime = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            prime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(prime == 0)
    {
        return 0; //It is not a prime number.
    }
    else
    {
        return 1; //It is a prime number.
    }
}

void delete_prime_number(struct node *p)
{
    struct node *q;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
        if((checkprime(q->data)) == 1)
        {
            free(q);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    insert(head, 0, 2);
    insert(head, 1, 3);
    insert(head, 2, 4);
    insert(head, 3, 7);
    insert(head, 4, 8);
    insert(head, 5, 12);
    insert(head, 6, 15);
    insert(head, 7, 23);
    display(head);
    delete_prime_number(head);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have tried for this. The problem is in the delete_prime_function. When I run it, it prints random values unlimited times.
I created a checkprime function which will return 1 if the number is prime and return 0 if the number is not prime.
Then in the delete_prime function, each time it would check the condition if((checkprime)==1), and if its true it would delete that node, and the process would go on until pointer "p" reaches NULL.
I'm not getting where I am doing it wrong.

**EDIT:**
Thank you, I implemented what @pmg and @VladfromMoscow pointed out. Here is the working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

int length(struct node *p)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        len++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return len;
}

void display(struct node *p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Linked List: ");
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", p->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}

void insert(struct node **p, int index, int x)
{
    struct node *t;
    
    if (index == 0)
    {
        t = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = x;
        t->next = *p;
        t->prev = NULL;
        if ((*p) != NULL)
        {
            (*p)->prev = t;
        }
        (*p) = t;
    }
    else
    {
        t = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = x;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            if((*p) == NULL)
            {
                printf("Linked List is empty!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                p = &(*p)->next;
            }    
        }
        t->prev = (*p);
        t->next = (*p)->next;
        if ((*p)->next != NULL)
        {
            (*p)->next->prev = t;
        }
        (*p)->next = t;
    }
}

int checkprime(int n)
{
    int prime = 1;
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime == 0)
        {
            return 0; //It is not a prime number.
        }
        else
        {
            return 1; //It is a prime number.
        }
    }  
}

void delete_prime_number(struct node **p)
{
    while (*p != NULL)
    {
        if (checkprime((*p)->data) == 1)
        {
            struct node *q = *p;
            if ((*p)->next != NULL)
            {
                (*p)->next->prev = (*p)->prev;
            }
            *p = (*p)->next;
            free(q);
        }
        else
        {
            p = &(*p)->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    insert(&head, 0, 2);
    insert(&head, 1, 3);
    insert(&head, 2, 4);
    insert(&head, 3, 7);
    insert(&head, 4, 8);
    insert(&head, 5, 12);
    insert(&head, 6, 15);
    insert(&head, 7, 23);
    display(head);
    delete_prime_number(&head);
    printf("\n");
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again :)

Comment: You must remove the node from your list. Just calling `free(q)` releases the memory and you are not allowed to access it again afterwards. But the address is still linked in your list.

Comment: Unrelated (but important): `if(n % 2 == 0)` ==> `if(n % i == 0)`

Comment: @pmg and also `for(int i=2; i<n; i++)` ==> `for(int i=2; i<n/i+1; i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the list is incorrect and many functions can invoke undefined behavior.

For starters the functions shall not rely on the global variable `head`. In this case a program for example can not use two lists simultaneously.

The function `length` invokes undefined behavior because the local variable `len` is not initialized.

```
int length(struct node *p)
{
    int len;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        len++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return len;
}
```

You need to write

```
    int len = 0;
```

In the function insert in this code snippet

```
    for(int i=0; i<index-1; i++)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    t->prev = p;
    t->next = p->next;
    if(p->next != NULL)
    {
        p->next->prev = t;
    }
    p->next = t;
```

you do not check whether `p` is equal to `NULL`. For example if the list is empty that is `head` is a null pointer and the user specified `index` equal to `1` then `p` also will be a null pointer. So using it in expressions like for example this  `p->next` invokes undefined behavior.

The function `checkprime` is also incorrect. It shows that numbers 0, 1 and all odd numbers are prime numbers due to the if statement

```
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        prime = 0;
        break;
    }
```

that will not get the control for such numbers.

So at first you have to write the list (declaring head as a local variable) and all the mentioned functions correctly before writing the function `delete_prime_number` which naturally also incorrect because at least it does not change the pointer head when the pointed node contains a prime number.

As for the function `delete_prime_number` itself then it can be defined the following wat

```
void delete_prime_number( struct node **head )
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( checkprime( ( *head )->data ) )
        {
            struct node *tmp = *head;

            if ( ( *head )->next != NULL )
            {
                ( *head )->next->prev = ( *head )->prev;
            }
            
            *head = ( *head )->next;
             
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

and can be called like

```
delete_prime_number( &head );
```

Comment: thanks, I corrected all the errors, and edited it in the question

Comment: @ranger You have not corrected all errors. For example as usual your function says that 0 and 1 are prime numbers.  In this loop for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            {
                p = &(*p)->next;
            } you are not checking whether p is equal to NULL.

Comment: ok, so I edited the mentioned errors again, I hope I did it right, thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this 3 nodes list:

```
NULL==p   /<==p   /<==p
      NODE    NODE    NODE
         n==>/   n==>/   n==NULL
```

When you remove the 2nd node in this list you want to get

```
NULL==p   /<==========p             // changed prev link in 3rd node
      NODE    ----    NODE          // deleted 2nd node
         n==========>/   n==NULL    // changed next link in 1st node
```

But your code is getting this

```
NULL==p    ----   /<==p             // prev links to deleted node
      NODE    ----    NODE
         n==>/   ----    n==NULL    // next links to deleted node
```

*Beware the special cases of the first and last nodes in the list.*

Comment: thanks, I get what I did wrong, will implement this again now